# After a successful install npm -g it is not reconized as internal command

Tags: environment-variables, npm

When I installed [ungit](https://github.com/FredrikNoren/ungit) and [imageoptim-cli](http://jamiemason.github.io/ImageOptim-CLI/) with npm
After I succefully had install :

```
npm install -g <name>
```

And I got :

```
<name>@<version>: <directory path>
```

when I call

```
name
```

in command line It said that 'name' is not reconized as an internal command ..
 Need help,  .. please .. Thanks ..

Comment: Can you please give more information about the library you try to install please?

Comment: I was trying to install UNGIT and IMAGEOPTIM-CLI. Thank you ..

Comment: Generally, what happen is that the directory where npm put those binaries is not in your $PATH. Can you tell us how you did install npm in the first place?

Comment: Agreed with @AurélienThieriot -- this sounds like a $PATH related issue.

Comment: So what do I have to do ? . Please help .

Answer (score 0):

You were right.
I added global nodemodul path 'C:\Users\my_name\npm' to my environement variables and now I get it working !! Thanks !